# Unity editor crashing after AssetBundle download completes

Tags: c#, crash, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I upgraded my project from Unity 4.5 to Unity 5.5.
Other developer had already made AssetBundles and uploaded it on server.
After upgrading the project when I am trying to download the asset bundles, my Unity editor is getting crashed. Here is my log:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycall.png
```

Comment: Version are matched correctly? Did this other developer upgraded asset bundle for the unity's 5.5 version?

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking in...actually I got the solution yesterday. I re-exported the assetBundles from Unity 5.5 and its working fine now. :)